# MySQL very occasional Unable to save result set

Tags: php, mysql

This is a production PHP/MySQL system that has been running for months, mostly without issue.

Very occasionally, like once every few weeks, I see "Unable to save result set" errors from a MySQL query.

I'm aware that this can be caused by a large result set, but that's not the case here.  In the most recent example, it happened for tiny table that usually has no more than 10 rows (rows represent active games, and they are removed after the games end---lots of turn-over, but always tiny).

The query is very simple:

```
SELECT player_1_id, player_2_id FROM minuetServer_games 
WHERE  ( player_1_id = '1513399' OR player_2_id = '1513399' )  
AND last_action_time < SUBTIME( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0 0:01:22.000' ) 
FOR UPDATE;
```

The point of this query is to find any active game for a given user_id (they can be either p1 or p2) that isn't too stale.  If one exists, I updated their game's last_action_time in the next query (of course, when the result set isn't saved, that update can't happen).

I ran CHECK TABLE and the result was OK.

What are the causes of spurious, occasional "Unable to save result set" warnings?  Is there a way to fix it?  Is there a solid work-around?

Edit:

A commenter requested more info about he PHP config. Here's a direct link to the output of phpinfo():

http://cordialminuet.com/info.php

Edit2:

Here's the code where the query is created:

```
global $tableNamePrefix;
cm_queryDatabase( "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0" );

global $moveTimeLimit;

$query = "SELECT player_1_id, player_2_id ".
    "FROM $tableNamePrefix"."games ".
    "WHERE ( player_1_id = '$user_id' OR player_2_id = '$user_id' ) ".
    " AND last_action_time < ".
    " SUBTIME( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$moveTimeLimit' ) FOR UPDATE;";

// watch for deadlock here and retry
$result = cm_queryDatabase( $query, 0 );
```

Here's the code for cm_queryDatabase:

```
function cm_queryDatabase( $inQueryString, $inDeadlockFatal=1 ) {
    global $cm_mysqlLink;
    if( gettype( $cm_mysqlLink ) != "resource" ) {
        // not a valid mysql link?
        cm_connectToDatabase();
        }
    $result = mysql_query( $inQueryString, $cm_mysqlLink );

    // a bunch of error handling here if $result is FALSE
    //  ......

    // then finally

    return $result;
    }
```

Here's the code for cm_connectToDatabase:

```
function cm_connectToDatabase( $inTrackStats = true) {
    global $databaseServer,
           $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName,
           $cm_mysqlLink;

    $cm_mysqlLink =
        mysql_connect( $databaseServer, 
                       $databaseUsername, $databasePassword );


    // bunch of error handling if $cm_mysqlLink is false
    // ....
    }
```

Note that "Unable to save result set" is a warning thrown by mysql_query.  Also, that this query is run hundreds of times a day without issue.  This warning happens spuriously once every few weeks at most.  Here's the most recent stack trace, from a few days ago:

```
Warning:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: Unable to save result set in /home/jcr14/public_html/gameServer/server.php on line 11248

#0  cm_noticeAndWarningHandler(2, mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: Unable to save result set, /home/jcr14/public_html/gameServer/server.php, 11248, Array ([inQueryString] => SELECT player_1_id, player_2_id FROM minuetServer_games WHERE  ( player_1_id = '1513399' OR player_2_id = '1513399' )  AND last_action_time <      SUBTIME( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0 0:01:22.000' ) FOR UPDATE;,[inDeadlockFatal] => 0,[cm_mysqlLink] => Resource id #4))

#1  mysql_query(SELECT player_1_id, player_2_id FROM minuetServer_games WHERE  ( player_1_id = '1513399' OR player_2_id = '1513399' )  AND last_action_time <      SUBTIME( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0 0:01:22.000' ) FOR UPDATE;, Resource id #4) called at [/home/jcr14/public_html/gameServer/server.php:11248]

#2  cm_queryDatabase(SELECT player_1_id, player_2_id FROM minuetServer_games WHERE  ( player_1_id = '1513399' OR player_2_id = '1513399' )  AND last_action_time <      SUBTIME( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0 0:01:22.000' ) FOR UPDATE;, 0) called at [/home/jcr14/public_html/gameServer/server.php:5979]
```

I'll look in the server logs for other examples from over the past few months.

Edit 3:

In the past 30 days (I'm flushing older log entries), this has happened five times.  Four of the occurrences were for the above query.  One occurrence happened for a different query:

```
SELECT next_magic_square_seed % 4294967296 
FROM minuetServer_server_globals FOR UPDATE;
```

This on is also called 100s of times a day without issue.  This is a table with a single row in it.

The surrounding code:

```
function cm_getNewSquare() {

    global $tableNamePrefix;

    // have it wrap around at the 32-bit unsigned max
    // because getMagicSquare6 takes a 32-bit unsigned seed.
    // we store it as a BIGINT to keep it from getting stuck on the same
    // square after four billion games

    $query = "SELECT next_magic_square_seed % 4294967296 ".
        "FROM $tableNamePrefix".
        "server_globals FOR UPDATE;";

    $result = cm_queryDatabase( $query );
```

Edit 4:

The table structure:

```
mysql> describe minuetServer_games;
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| game_id               | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| creation_time         | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_action_time      | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_1_id           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| player_2_id           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dollar_amount         | decimal(11,2)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| amulet_game           | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| amulet_game_wait_time | datetime            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| started               | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| round_number          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| game_square           | char(125)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_1_got_start    | tinyint(4)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_2_got_start    | tinyint(4)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_1_moves        | char(13)            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_2_moves        | char(13)            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_1_bet_made     | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_2_bet_made     | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_1_ended_round  | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_2_ended_round  | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| move_deadline         | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_1_coins        | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_2_coins        | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_1_pot_coins    | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_2_pot_coins    | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| settled_pot_coins     | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| semaphore_key         | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
26 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The CREATE statement:

```
 "CREATE TABLE $tableName(" .
"game_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," .
"creation_time DATETIME NOT NULL,".
"last_action_time DATETIME NOT NULL,".
"player_1_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL," .
"INDEX( player_1_id )," .
"player_2_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL," .
"INDEX( player_2_id )," .
"dollar_amount DECIMAL(11, 2) NOT NULL,".
"INDEX( dollar_amount )," .
"amulet_game TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,".
"INDEX( amulet_game ),".
// wait for a random amount of time before
// settling on an opponent for an amulet game
"amulet_game_wait_time DATETIME NOT NULL,".
"INDEX( amulet_game_wait_time ),".
"started TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,".
"round_number INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL," .
// 36-cell square, numbers from 1 to 36, separated by #
// character
"game_square CHAR(125) NOT NULL,".
// flag set when each player requests the very first game
// state. This indicates that both are aware that the game
// has started, so leave penalties can be assessed
"player_1_got_start TINYINT NOT NULL,".
"player_2_got_start TINYINT NOT NULL,".
"player_1_moves CHAR(13) NOT NULL,".
"player_2_moves CHAR(13) NOT NULL,".
"player_1_bet_made TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,".
"player_2_bet_made TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,".
"player_1_ended_round TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,".
"player_2_ended_round TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,".
"move_deadline DATETIME NOT NULL,".
"player_1_coins TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ".
"player_2_coins TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ".
"player_1_pot_coins TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ".
"player_2_pot_coins TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ".
// coins in both pots that are common knowledge to both players
// (coins that have been matched by opponent to move on
// to next turn)
"settled_pot_coins TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ".
"semaphore_key INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ) ENGINE = INNODB;"
```

Comment: This is a PHP error, not a MySQL one.  To identify the problem, you'll need to provide further information about the PHP context in which you are executing this command.

Comment: No, not the phpinfo - !the php code which generates and applies the update.

Comment: First of all - stop using `mysql` extension as it is **deprecated**. Try to rewrite your code to use **`mysqli`** or **`pdo`** instead.

Comment: @PaulTomkiel: For what is clearly a large incumbent project with a significant existing codebase, that's probably not a terribly helpful suggestion right now...

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming that this rare bug is not caused by my use of the mysql extension.  Also, this install is running PHP 5.3.28, where mysql_query is NOT deprecated (it wasn't deprecated until 5.5).  Also, I should mention that I have a number of large PHP/MySQL projects, and each one sees "Unable to save result set" occasionally.  If it's a known bug in the mysql extension, then ok, but otherwise, that's a lot of code to change as an experiment.

Comment: @eggyal - you're right. Those two functions doesn't seem very complicated, so that was my blind catch. All similar issues i've almost always had to do with disk or memory space/management. Do you have something in your syslog with similar timestamp?

Comment: The “Unable to save result set” error is generally associated with major MySQL problems, like a corrupt table or faulty install. In some cases Repairing the MySQL database fixes this, even though CHECK TABLE reported no problems at all.

Comment: Is it possible that your query would conflict with the lock of another execution of that same query? From the condition, it looks as though the same line(s) could be selected if there were three players (one of them playing with the two others) active at the same time. It would be consistent (?) with eggyal hint that the result is null while the field count is positive (wild guesses here)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: The MySQL documentation is clear regarding the circumstances in which this failure can occur, and it is not due to conflicting locks (which would normally just result in one query being queued until those locks are released, possibly timing out—unless there is a deadlock in which case that is the error that would be raised).

Comment: @JasonRohrer Could you add `minuetServer_games` structure to your post please? `CREATE TABLE` statement would be helpfull.

Comment: I am just really completely guessing, but: could it be a race condition and optimistic locking? Select for update does something with transactions. What if a different session did a write?

Answer (score 5):

1. > What are the causes of spurious, occasional "Unable to save result set" warnings?

   Sadly this error is not very well documented in the PHP manual.  So, let's RTFS!

   Looking through the source code for your version of `ext/mysql`, the error `"Unable to save result set"` [appears only once](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3.28/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c#L1486):

   ```c
       if(use_store == MYSQL_USE_RESULT) {
           mysql_result=mysql_use_result(mysql->conn);
       } else {
           mysql_result=mysql_store_result(mysql->conn);
       }
       if (!mysql_result) {
           if (PHP_MYSQL_VALID_RESULT(mysql->conn)) { /* query should have returned rows */
               php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Unable to save result set");
   ```

   Looking at [the definition](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3.28/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c#L115) of the `PHP_MYSQL_VALID_RESULT` macro:

   ```c
   #define PHP_MYSQL_VALID_RESULT(mysql)       \
       (mysql_field_count(mysql)>0)
   ```

   It's clear that, for this error to arise, `mysql_store_result()` must return `NULL` yet `mysql_field_count()` must return a positive number.  The MySQL C API [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-field-count.html) for the latter function states:

   > The normal use of this function is when [`mysql_store_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-store-result.html) returned `NULL` (and thus you have no result set pointer). In this case, you can call [`mysql_field_count()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-field-count.html) to determine whether [`mysql_store_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-store-result.html) should have produced a nonempty result. This enables the client program to take proper action without knowing whether the query was a [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) (or [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html)-like) statement.

   Well, that seems to describe exactly the situation that has arisen in your case.  Following the link therein to [Section 23.8.15.1, “Why mysql_store_result() Sometimes Returns NULL After mysql_query() Returns Success”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/null-mysql-store-result.html):

   > It is possible for [`mysql_store_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-store-result.html) to return `NULL` following a successful call to [`mysql_query()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-query.html). When this happens, it means one of the following conditions occurred:
   >
   > - There was a `malloc()` failure (for example, if the result set was too large).
   > - The data could not be read (an error occurred on the connection).
   > - The query returned no data (for example, it was an [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html), [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html), or [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html)).

   Since the condition arose whilst you were performing `SELECT` queries, and there is no indication of an error on the connection (which *I imagine* would be dropped by the client if that were the case), it would therefore appear that the most likely cause of this error is a `malloc()` failure.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12434865) gives a very good explanation of the circumstances in which `malloc()` can fail.
2. > Is there a way to fix it?

   Of course there is, yes!  But it could well involve detailed analysis into why MySQL's attempt to allocate memory failed in this instance.  My guess would be that your hosting environment limits the memory available to MySQL, and that memory allocation has been reached.

   Perhaps simply increasing the memory available to MySQL would help?  Otherwise, you might like to read through [How MySQL Uses Memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/memory-use.html) and start tweaking some server settings…
3. > Is there a solid work-around?

   You might simply reattempt the query in the event that this condition arises?

Comment: Op tested on a max 10 row table with a memory_limit of 96M. RTFS lulz when reading 3rd paragraph of ops post. Lots of good info regardless eggyal.

Comment: @Brian: Just because the query in question was small *does not mean* that MySQL didn't run out of memory.  For example, if MySQL was already consuming all but 1KiB of its memory allocation, the tiniest of queries could still result in `malloc()` failure.  Not sure what is meant by your second sentence?

Comment: The curious thing is that the error and warning gets logged through my custom logging mechanism, which actually inserts log entries into the same database from the same thread and connection.  Coupled with the fact that 20K queries a day are running just fine, it's strange that this failure happens only sporadically.

Comment: Also strange that it mostly seems to happen on this particular query and not others (there are dozens of other queries that are much more memory-intensive).  I have implemented a work-around that simply retries the same query one time.  I'll see if that works.

Comment: Finally, that 96M limit in PHP is per-connection, right?  So if MySQL is running out of memory, we're talking about the PHP thread for the connection (the mysql client) running out of memory, not mysqld running out of memory, right?  But why would this PHP thread run out of memory when it's not doing very much?  Finally, there are a bunch of persistent httpd procs on my server that are sleeping for new connections.  Are each of those keeping a running malloc pool for new PHP connections?  So if there's a leak in PHP's use of memory, they'd run out of memory over time?

Comment: @JasonRohrer: Aah, yes you're quite right.  I was being rather stupid (and for some reason thought we were talking about mysqld running out of memory)—but obviously it's libmysql (the client library) that encountered problems.  Since libmysql runs outside of PHP's memory management, it won't be affected by PHP's 96MiB limit... perhaps some other restriction in the OS is interfering?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this issue sorted by freeing up my server disk space as my server hit 100% usage.

This issue has been logged in /var/log/mysql/error.log, so I always check the error log first before I do anything.