# c++ std::bad_alloc with around 20,000,000x6 double records

Tags: c++, matlab, heap-memory, record

I have a MATLAB code which is working perfectly over 20,000,000×6 double records.

I converted same code to cC++ and use vector to store those records, but it give me `bad_alloc` problem.

This is my structre:

```
typedef struct Affine 
{
  double a11;
  double a12;
  double a13;
  double a21;
  double a22;
  double a23;
};
```

I have one vector storing initial guess of configs named as configs, which holds 20,000,000× `Affine` records.

I have to change these records into affine which I created like this.

```
Affine affines;

 affines.a11 = 0;
 affines.a12 = 0;
 affines.a13 = 0;
 affines.a21 = 0;
 affines.a22 = 0;
 affines.a23 = 0;

 vector<Affine> matrixConfigs_mex(configs.size(), affines);
```

but it fails to allocate memory.

I have 10GB of RAM, MATLAB is working perfect with same number of configs.
Can some one help and tell me how to fix this ?

`configs.max_size()`  returns 89,478,485

Environment 
Windows 7
10GB ram,
Microsoft Visual Studio 2015
Matlab 2015.

Example to check my code is as follows:

```
// Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Affine 
{
  double a11;
  double a12;
  double a13;
  double a21;
  double a22;
  double a23;
};

int main()
{        
    Affine affine;

    affine.a11 = 0.1;
    affine.a12 = 0.1;
    affine.a13 = 0.1;
    affine.a21 = 0.1;
    affine.a22 = 0.1;
    affine.a23 = 0.1;

    std::vector<Affine> test1(20000000, affine);
    std::vector<Affine> test(test1.size(), affine);

    std::cout << test[10000].a11;
}
```

Comment: What operating system? What compiler? What command line?

Comment: i added it into description.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate using Visual Studio 2015](http://rextester.com/RKSAJ1423)

Comment: same environment ? configs and matrixConfigs_mex both have more than  20000000 records

Comment: @Mudasar Please post a [mcve] that duplicates the issue.  The link shows that there is no issue with 20000000 `Affine` objects in the vector.

Comment: What does `20000000x6` mean? 120millions?

Comment: @sfk92fksdf measa that 6 records of structure.

Comment: @Mudasar `6 records of structure.` -- That is not clear.  Is it a vector of 20000000 Affine objects?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes you are right.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie check example i posted

Comment: So you creating 2 vectors? That's 2GB and it [fails](http://rextester.com/AOPDM18478). I guess it's OS is what constraining your program from allocating that much memory.For example it doesn't have two continuous 1GB chunks of memory or you exceed space provided to you process (which is 2GB [on 32-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1034081/4440694))

Comment: @ sfk92fksdf 1.2Gb is limit on 32bit Windows 7 actually, unless binary is large address aware(look it up). But if OP uses x64 , he should check if he actually compiles  64bit code.

Comment: Each vector is 960 MB, and a 32 bit process has a 2 GB virtual address space; they are not going to fit (especially since `std::vector` requires contiguous memory, and the virtual address space contains other stuff besides your vectors). The fact that you have 10 GB of RAM is completely irrelevant, what is constraining you here is the size of the virtual address space, which is fixed. The simplest way to overcome the problem and exploit the RAM you have is to compile your program in 64 bit mode.

Comment: @sfk92fksdf thank you for answer. My OP is 64bit, let me check 64bit code compilation.

Comment: @Swift I found the number [1.75GB](http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0036/), but again, it's a theoretical number so actual amount is hard to guess :)

Comment: It actually depends strongly on the size of the single allocations and on the dlls/stuff that may be loaded. If the antivirus dll injected in all the processes is forced to be loaded at the 1 GB boundary you aren't going to allocate any single block bigger than that.

Comment: @sfk92fksdf That's total size of Image I think, 2Gb minus stuff that OS uses. heap is smaller, but yeah, you're right, defragmentation also plays role. I was rolling of assumption that it is VS and MS's runtime